# Try-except with NameError and TypeError

Tags: python, error-handling, try-except

Can you please help me with the following. I am trying to catch two exceptions: 1) `TypeError` and 2)`NameError`. I use the following code below that estimates the average:

```
def calculate_average(number_list):
    try:
        if type(number_list) is not list:
            raise ValueError("You should pass list to this function")
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
        return
    try:
        average = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
    
    except TypeError:
        print('List should contain numbers')
        return
    except NameError:
        print('List should contain numbers')
        return
 
    return average
```

The code works fine for:

```
print(calculate_average([1, 2, 3]))
print(calculate_average([1, 2, 'a']))
```

But when I use:

```
print(calculate_average([1, 2, a]))
```

I have the following error that was supposed to be captured by `except`:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Can you please help me with understanding the issue? (I use Spyder)

Comment: The error is raised before you even enter the function. When you try to run `print(calculate_average([1, 2, a]))` `a` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NameError` on `a` is raised in the *calling* scope, not when you attempt to use `number_list`. You would need to catch it there:

```
try:
    print(calculate_average([1, 2, a]))
except NameError:
    print("Variable not defined")
```

However, you shouldn't be catching `NameError`s at all. When they arise in *testing*, you should figure out what undefined name you are trying to use, and make sure it *is* defined. Like most exceptions, this isn't intended for flow control or dealing with easily fixed problems at runtime.

---

Rather than littering your code with run-time type check, consider using type hints and static typecheckers like `mypy` to catch code that would *produce* a `TypeError` at runtime.

```
# list[int] might be too restrictive, but this is a simplified
# example
def calculate_average(number_list: list[int]):
    
    average = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
    return average
```

They only error left here that `mypy` wouldn't catch is the attempt to divide by zero if you pass an empty list. *That* you can check for and handle. You can raise a `ValueError`, or just decide that the average of an empty list is 0 by definition.

```
def calculate_average(number_list: list[int]):
    if not number_list:
        # raise ValueError("Cannot average an empty list")
        return 0

    return sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
```

This is preferable to

```
try:
    return sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    ...
```

because it anticipates the problem before you go to the trouble of calling `sum` and `len`.

Answer (score 0):

In spyder, if you look in the trail of recent tracebacks, the error is raised by site-package `...lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec(code, globals, locals)` , as `NameError: name 'a' is not defined` since it searches for a variable declaration of a in the script (which is absent), before executing the function.